# Pax- Exam @Configuration is deprecated in 4.6.0

Tags: pax-exam

In the newer version of Pax-Exam @configuration is deprecated. How do we use configuration in newer versions?..Any sample code?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about `org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.Configuration`.

A look at the Javadoc or source code of that class reveals the replacement to use:
`org.ops4j.pax.exam.Configuration`.